# Expiration date on Argentina ETA (AVE)

Tags: applications, argentina, eta, canadian-residents

I am thinking to travel to Argentina in August (Specifically on August 18th). Since, I am an eligible citizen for ETA (or AVE in Spanish), I decided to go for it.

Thinking that it will be valid for 3 months, and the process might take days, I decided to apply for it on May 18th. Surprisingly, it was approved the same day. When I opened the visa, I realized that when they say 3 months, they meant actually 90 days. As a result, my ETA is now valid only until 16th. All my tickets are confirmed (Since I have never considered this situation or where my visa would be refused).

**I would like to know if anyone who has applied for an ETA (or AVE) for Argentina has similar issue? And how did you end up solving it?**

I am not even dare to pay again and apply again since I am uncertain if the system will just automatically reject my application seeing I already have a valid one. (I am not sure neither if I am eligible for going through the regular visa process - visa sticker - for having a "valid" ETA)

Any suggestion or experience are very helpful (Really want to visit Argentina and not change my itinerary) Thanks!!

Comment: It appears that you should be able to apply to extend your stay after your arrival https://www.argentina.gob.ar/interior/migraciones/turistas

Comment: @Traveller It appears that the Visa is only valid up until 2 days before the OP has booked to arrive in Argentina.  So they may need a time machine to extend it after their arrival.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to answer my own question here in case some one out there has the same situation as me and can't find any more help.

What I ended up doing was (and I successfully went to Argentina in August without a problem) asked the embassy to issue me a visa sticker by paying again.

So the solution is kind of easy, and they told me explicitly that it is okay. They couldn't do anything with my ETA (AVE) because it belongs to the Ministry of Migration (whereas embassies fall under the jurisdiction of Ministry of Foreign Affairs)

I simply sent over some documents (indeed more than you need to apply for AVE but it is not hard for me to prepare. Requirements might vary by embassies). I then went there for a small interview where they just asked me some questions like how long I will be spending and where.

I received my visa in two days, and it is valid for only 3 months as usual.

The agent at the border didn't say a word when I go through, and the entire process was very smooth